# Flask-Admin: Custom Query for Select Field with Peewee?

Tags: python, flask, peewee, flask-admin

I have a model with a ForeignKeyField which gets rendered as a select field in the create/edit form in Flask-Admin. I would like to restrict the choices in the select field with a custom query so the user only has access to their own source addresses.

All answers point I've found point in the direction of WTForms' [QuerySelectField](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields) but that is only for SQLAlchemy and I am using Peewee.

It seems like a pretty common thing to do though, so any other way?

`class BulkMessage(BaseModel):
    title = CharField(null=True)
    source_address = ForeignKeyField(
        SourceAddress,
        related_name='bulk_messages',
        null=True
    )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple, actually:

Just override `edit_form` in the `ModelView` and create the field there with the query passed in `choices`, as seen in the [docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField):

```
def edit_form(self):
    form = model_form(BulkMessage)

    form.source_address = SelectField(
        'Source Address',
        choices=[(sa.id, sa.title) for sa in SourceAddress.select().where(SourceAddress.owner == current_user.id)]
    )

    return form(obj=obj)
```